# Create multiple powerpoint slide-decks in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, for-loop, r-markdown, powerpoint

I've recently started using RMarkdown and can already see the benefits of it. Right now I need to create a report in the form of a powerpoint-presentation out of the results of a questionnaire. I've written a script in RMarkdown that reads a dataset, tidy the data and put in a long format, and then knit a powerpoint-deck with some generic slides along with multiple barcharts, each one populating a slide. This is all well and fine, and gives me a powerpoint that is ok. Thing is, I need to create this powerpoint for multiple different groups (100+) using the same data. Essentially, I would like to `group_by` in an early step and then create the same powerpoint-presentation (but obviously with different results) for every single group. But I can't figure out how to do this!? Could anyone help?